# How can I alter the spotlight category spreadsheets to include ODS

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, libreoffice

In Lion, the "All My Files" smart folder in finder is based on spotlight search categories. While I can see how from System Preferences->Spotlight->Search Results I can alter the order of these as well as enabled/disable categories, I cannot see how to alter the file types that go into them.

I specifically want to add the Libre Office ODS file type into spreadsheets, but a generalised answer I can use for other file types is even better.

I don't fear cracking out vi and editing system files.

Answer (score 2):

Install "LibreOffice", latest version. It contains the aforementioned mdiimporter plugin. Confirmed just now, to be working. LibreOffice 3.5.6 on OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Danny

Spotlight integration for OSX app created documents rely on the application developer building in support for Spotlight for bespoke file types.

The plugins mdimporter (metadata importer) for Spotlight and qlgenerator for QuickLook are included within the application package and registered when the application is first run.

Those plugins are application bundles in their own right.  So without developer input from the LibreOffice developers, you won't get Spotlight integration.

[Spotlight Developer pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/MDImporters.html)

**Update 10/10/2012**
According to the LibreOffice bug lists, SpotLight integration for LibreOffice file formats has been around for some time, however there have been some issues. I can confirm that 3.5.6 on Mountain Lion does now appear to work correctly.

Comment: Hmm - it is OSS - so this is pretty much DIY maybe. I wander if there are any Libre or Open office bundlings for OSX that have tighter integration with stuff like that?